# Expanable navigation drawer list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, expandablelistview, android-navigation

I need to show an expandable list inside the Navigation Drawer. How can I achieve that.
I've done creating only a list by this code

```
String [] menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry   Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
       dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
        dList.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

I tried to change `R.layout to expandable list` but it's crashed with null pointer Exception. I believe I need to set the array content to suit the list but i don't know how. I need to make subs for "android" for example.

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private  String[] planets;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
        //listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,object));
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets ));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    //public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Toast.makeText(this, planets[position] + "was selected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Intent    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
        //intent.putExtra("sometext", temp.getText());
        //intent.putExtra("sometext", planets[position]);
        //startActivity(intent);

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, third.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

        //selectItem(position);
    }

//  public void selectItem(int position) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      
//  }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <!-- android:entries="@array/planets" -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

mainfest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="planets">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
    </string-array>
```